# Formula to edit part of a text in one cell based on an values in another cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-online

I'm looking for an excel based formula for one of my projects which can help in removing certain parts of a cell (Cell A - names separated by a based on the values in Cell B (similar format as Cell A). I'm running a flow on this file as well hence cannot run VBA based solutions as my connector is excel online.

Example

Cell A - cat;dog;rat;rabbit

Cell B - rabbit;dog

Result needs to be - cat;rat

Answer (score 0):

For O365 Beta Channel:

`=TEXTJOIN(";",,UNIQUE(TEXTSPLIT(A1&";"&B1,,";"),,1))`

All O365 users (though works only in the desktop version, not online):

`=TEXTJOIN(";",,UNIQUE(FILTERXML("<a><b>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1&";"&B1,";","</b><b>")&"</b></a>","//b"),,1))`

For Excel Online:

`=TEXTJOIN(";",,UNIQUE(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A1&";"&B1,";",REPT(" ",99)),99*SEQUENCE(1+LEN(A1&";"&B1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1&";"&B1,";","")),,0)+1,99)),,1))`

Comment: Thank you for your input Jos. Is there any alternative for excel online?

Comment: @GithinMathewGeorge Added an option for Excel Online

Comment: This alternative works although it still gives me an error while applying to my mailing list. An extra semi-colon (;) gets added every 102 characters. Any solution for this issue?

Comment: Given that it works for the dataset you posted, suggest you post some more realisitic data.